# Read() after poll returns POLLIN and POLLERR

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, poll-syscall

I have an aysnc threadpool model for my network connection management. A single dispatcher thread that keeps calling poll() and a worker thread pool that either
read/write once poll() indicates so.

Consider a case where poll() indicates a socket is read-ready. But the worker thread hasn't processed the read yet. I disable read-poll while the worker thread hasn't processed the read. Now the remote side disconnects and poll()
returns with POLLERR/POLLHUP. What happens when the worker thread does the read() call after this?

Does read() return <0 even though there is some data that hasn't been read yet? Or

Does read() read data from the network even though the socket had a POLLERR/POLLHUP?

Answer (score 0):

All the pending data will be delivered before `read()` returns zero. However if `read()` returns -1, pending data may have been lost.

Comment: Does it deliver the data even if there was a POLLERR after POLLIN?

Comment: I can only repeat what I said above, and I'm not going to do that.